# Document field (date) return null

Tags: symfony, datetime, doctrine-odm

Good day. There was such problem.

```
/**
 * @ODM\Document
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ODM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ODM\Date
     */
    private $createdAt;

...

}
```

In controller persisted test document. At the base of enrolled:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5603ece1147fe7322c8b4581"), "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-09-24T11:27:04Z") }
```

But when I make a selection from the controller, I get a null in createdAt:

```
Test {#531 ▼
  -id: "5603ece1147fe7322c8b4581"
  -createdAt: null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`createdAt` is not initialized. You can set it's value in the constructor.

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime("now");
}
```